# Deselecting option from BindableRadioGroup in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using [this](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/e23832282b312cc6da6495da82f29081635fe1bb/source/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/RadioButton/BindableRadioGroup.cs) control from XLabs project. Binding and selecting works fine, but I am using this control in some kind of survey and I would like to deselect the previous answer (option in this control) after client click `Next` button to see next question. Any ideas how to do this?

```
<controls:BindableRadioGroup 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}"
                SelectedIndex="{Binding AnswerSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Style="{StaticResource radioGroupStyle}" />
```

The command binded to the button:

```
public IAsyncCommand NextCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new AwaitableDelegateCommand(async () => await Next(), CanGoToNextQuestion);
        }
    }
```

and methods:

```
private async Task Next()
    {
        CurrentQuestionIndex++;

        AnsweredQuestions.Add(
            new QuestionDto
            {
                QuestionId = CurrentQuestion.QuestionId,
                QuestionText = CurrentQuestion.QuestionText,
                Answer = Answers.ElementAt(AnswerSelected).Value,
            });

            // some stuff here


        AnswerSelected = -1;
    }

    private bool CanGoToNextQuestion()
    {
        return AnswerSelected != -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is not very elegant and not in MVVM style but is working. Code posted below should be placed in CodeBehind in the View.

```
    void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearRadioGroup();
    }

    private void ClearRadioGroup()
    {
        foreach (var child in grupa.Children)
        {
            var radio = (CustomRadioButton)child;
            radio.Checked = false;
        }
    }
```